# How Django-allauth signal/adapter flow works ?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have implemented Django-allauth using Facebook as a social account provider as it gives lots of information about its users.
Below is my custom signup form:

> ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'profiles.forms.MySignupForm'

```
class MySignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MySignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.fields["email"].widget.input_type = "email"  # ugly hack
    self.helper.form_method = "POST"
    self.helper.form_action = "account_signup"
    self.helper.form_id = "signup_form"
    self.helper.form_class = "signup"
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Field('email', placeholder="Enter Email", autofocus=""),
        Field('first_name', placeholder="Enter First Name"),
        Field('last_name', placeholder="Enter Last Name"),
        Field('password1', placeholder="Enter Password"),
        Field('password2', placeholder="Re-enter Password"),
        Submit('sign_up', 'Sign up', css_class="btn-warning"),
    )

def signup(self, request, user):
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.save()

*What else can be added here in signup form ???  or to do the processing on received input i need to write adapter ??*
```

I have below signal receiver implemented.

```
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def set_initial_user_names(request, user, sociallogin=None, **kwargs):
     if sociallogin:
        ***grab the data***
        email_verified = sociallogin.account.extra_data['verified']
        profile = models.Profile(user=user, avatar_url=picture_url, email_verified=email_verified)
        profile.save() <--- *saving custom user profile here*
        from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
        emails = EmailAddress.objects.filter(user=user, email=user.email)
        for email in emails:
            email.verified = email_verified
            email.save()  <--- *saving allauth Email Address instance.* 
        user.guess_display_name()
        user.save() <----- *saving custom user model based on email address.*
```

Now if you see i am verifying if email is verified by social account(Facebook) if so i am updating Email Address instance of allauth.

But it happens twice. 
allauth already updates the email address instance (account_emailaddress) during the login/sign up process. So database is getting hit twice for account_emailaddress table.

I want to control this scenario myself so that it only does it once..
Answer is Adapter, but if i write adapter, what happens to the signal receiver ??
Can someone tell me the adapter/signal flow ??    how it should be implemented. ?? 
I have gone through the documentation but still it would be nice if i get some direction on the flow like at which stage what i can control !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `ModelForm` for your custom signup form, as `allauth` needs to be in charge of constructing a User instance and saving it. Make it a plain form, simply deriving from `django.forms.Form`. Only use it in cases when you need to add additional inputs during signup. Looking at your form it seems you are not adding any additional fields, so you probably don't need a custom form at all.

Use the following form to ask users for their first/last name:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
```

Comment: I am using custom user model with email as a username and first/last names are required fields.     
If i dont use custom signup form then all auth signup form only asks for email and password.    

Also can you comment on receiver i mentioned above ?    
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also i see strange behavior when i use django.forms.Form vs django.forms.ModelForm

if i use just django.forms.Form then first/last name does not appear in sign up form but if i use django.forms.ModelForm it does..


Confused...

Comment: See my updated answer for an example on first/last name. As for Form vs ModelForm my answer stands -- ModelForm is not to be used, it will get you into trouble. The User model has already been taken care of by `allauth`,  the custom SignupForm is only meant for additional questions.